# I cannot get the staffs from the SQLIte DB to iOS table view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am stuck in iOS application that works on SQLite. I have created a Coffee table with different types of coffee names and prices along with the coffee ID which acts as the primary key. In SQLite I could run the SQL queries and got the correct answers. But while getting the coffee names in iOS table view, I got nothing except the blank table and section title. While debugging the code I found that **while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW)** is not working as **sqlite3_step(selectstmt)** returns 101 value (i.e. **SQLITE_DONE**) instead of **SQLITE_ROW (i.e value 100)** even if I tried with **sqlite3_reset()** before executing **sqlite3_step()**.
I could not figure out how to solve it.

Here is my code of coffee.m

```
#import "Coffee.h"

#import "SQLAppDelegate.h"

static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *deleteStmt = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;


@implementation Coffee

@synthesize coffeeID, coffeeName, price, isDirty, isDetailViewHydrated;

- (void) dealloc {

    [price release];
    [coffeeName release];
    [super dealloc];
}

+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath{


    SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK){
        
        const char *sql = "select CoffeeID, CoffeeName from Coffee";
                
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt = nil;
                
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL)== SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_reset(selectstmt);
            //NSLog(@"Macro %d",sqlite3_step(selectstmt));
            
               while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
                
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt,0);
                NSLog(@"The P key is %d:",primaryKey);
                Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                coffeeObj.coffeeName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;
                [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];
                [coffeeObj release];
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        sqlite3_close(database);
}

- (id) initWithPrimaryKey:(NSInteger ) pk{

    [super init];
    coffeeID = pk;
    NSLog(@"%d",coffeeID);
    isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
    
    return self;
}

+ (void)finalizeStatements {

    if(database) 
        sqlite3_close(database);
}

@end
```

+++++++++++++ RootViewController.m +++++++++++++

```
\#import "RootViewController.h"

\#import "Coffee.h"


@implementation RootViewController


\#pragma mark -

\#pragma mark View lifecycle


\- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    
    appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    
    self.title = @"Name List";//Coffee List;
    
    
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


\#pragma mark -

\#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.

\- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.

\- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"Rows %d",[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]);

    return [appDelegate.coffeeArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

\- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    
    // Configure the cell.

    Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = coffeeObj.coffeeName;

    return cell;
}
```

+++++++++++++ SQLAppDelegate.m +++++++++++++

```
\#import "SQLAppDelegate.h"

\#import "RootViewController.h"

\#import "Coffee.h"


@implementation SQLAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

@synthesize navigationController;

@synthesize coffeeArray;


\#pragma mark -

\#pragma mark Application lifecycle


\- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded {
    
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSError *error;

    NSString *dbPath = [self getDBPath];

//  NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);

    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    NSLog(@"%d",success);

    if(!success){
    
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoffeeDetail.sqlite"];

        success =[fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        
        if(!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);

    }
    
}

\- (NSString *)getDBPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    
        NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    //NSLog(@"dbpath %@",[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SQL.sqlite"]);

    return [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoffeeDetail.sqlite"];
}

\- (void) removeCoffee:(Coffee *)coffeeObj{

    //Delete from DataBase

    [coffeeObj deleteCoffee];
    
    //Delete from the array

    [coffeeArray removeObject:coffeeObj];
    
}


\- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
    
    NSMutableArray *tempArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.coffeeArray = tempArray;
    
    [tempArray release];
                                
    [Coffee getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];

    NSLog(@"Array =%@", self.coffeeArray);  
                        
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

\- (void) deleteCoffee{

            if(deleteStmt == nil){
    
            const char *sql = "delete from Coffee where coffeeID = ?";

           if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)

            NSAssert1(0,@"Error while creating the delete Statement. '%s'",    sqlite3_errmsg(database));
             }
    
                sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, coffeeID);
    
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt))
                    NSAssert1(0,@"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    
            sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in `deleteCoffee` you're trying to use a variable that isn't set (`database`).

In my sqlite apps I have this method:

```
-(sqlite3 *) getNewDBConnection{
    sqlite3 *newDBconnection;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.sqlite"];
    // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &newDBconnection) == SQLITE_OK) {

        //NSLog(@"Database Successfully Opened");

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error in opening database");
    }

    return newDBconnection; 
}
```

and then in the methods that access the DB, I have something like:

```
- (void) deleteCoffee{
        sqlite3 *database = [self getNewDBConnection]; //see this line
        if(deleteStmt == nil){

        const char *sql = "delete from Coffee where coffeeID = ?";

       if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)

        NSLog(@"Error while creating the delete Statement. '%s'",    sqlite3_errmsg(database));
         }

            sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, coffeeID);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt))
                NSLog(@"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);

}
```

Comment: Get it... Here I have to insert the rows into the database from the terminal and not from the SQLite Manager editor.

Comment: so are you saying your table was empty? I've used the SQLite Manager for Firefox and it worked okay, but I had used the wrong line terminator for excel so it would only insert the first line...I can't remember what the proper one was, but I think it was either `\r\n` or `\t\n`

Comment: An erratic behavior is observed. I could execute the commands in SQLite Manager and it works fine. But somehow the table view of the iOS simulator could not load the data from the table created by SQLite Manager. If I could create a table abd insert the rows in a single shot by using Terminal utility, then the code works, but later when I add some more rows and run the code, the old rows are exhibited, it could take the updated data into account and make it appeared on the table.

Comment: did you create an editable version of the DB before making changes? some code here: http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/ (see the `createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded` method)

Comment: Yes.. I did that.... I think if I could add data to the database by the code, then it is reflected on the iPod table view, else updation of the database could not be loaded!!

Comment: I think you will probably need to post your table code as well

Comment: I have posted mt RootViewController.m and SQLAppDelegate.m files

Comment: I don't know if I understand your situation anymore, is this correct: you are successfully able to populate the table in your sqlite DB using the terminal, and see that data in the table, but if you add more rows, they don't appear? Or do you mean you still haven't gotten any data out of the DB?

Comment: If I would add more rows.. it would not appear. The code gives result only of those rows which are inserted in the same session when the table is created (Via terminal).... If i would add some more rows to the database later, the added rows would not appear in the result. But the correct information is printing if (select * from Coffee) is executed via the terminal or SQLite Manager..

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're updating the db via terminal, but the ACTUAL file that the app is querying is the version in the simulator... So each time you modify the DB, you should delete the app and reinstall. In your app can users add data? Or is it all sourced from you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No, in my app users cannot add data. Could you give me a code snippet to delete and reinstall the app each time I modify the DB?

Comment: I just click and hold on the app in the simulator, then delete it...I'm not sure that's required, but in the past I had trouble getting the new data recognized, and that fixed it (but there might be a better way)

Comment: I took the help of code snippet to add data from my apps. The tableview  of the simulator adds / deletes the data but there is no reflection of add/delete on the .sqlite database. In a tutorial, it is said to figure out the application guid to find the updated .sqlite database which may be located in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/App GUID/ but in my case I have found no Application folder under ..iPhone Simulator/User directory

Comment: can you post your `deleteCoffee` method?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I have posted my deleteCoffee method as per your suggestion. I appreciate your help and time.

Comment: are you getting the `Error while deleting` error? what does it say? I think the `database` variable you have in `deleteCoffee` is nil...I edited my answer above with some more code

Comment: oh, I see you have it set up at the very top, I missed that. but still, what error are you getting? (I changed it to `NSLog`s in my code instead of `NSAssert`)

Comment: I am getting no error. The coffee item is deleted from the simulator list. but there is no such deletion in original SQLite DB. How could i reflect the change done in the iOS simulator to the SQLite DB?

Comment: well if it's not actually completing the deletion, you should be getting the error portion of your deleteCoffee method, so something must be wrong there, maybe change the Asserts to Logs and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But in a tutorial, it is said to figure out the application guid to find the updated .sqlite database which may be located in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/App GUID/ but in my case I have found no Application folder under ..iPhone Simulator/User directory.

Comment: OH, I just now realized what you're saying about the ORIGINAL DB...no, that won't change, just the installed version, but the app is only using that version, so there should be no issue...if you want the users to be changing a SINGLE database that all users access, you won't use the local SQLite, you'll need a hosted DB and web services that the users will use to make changes to the DB